# How to increase QNetworkReply::downloadProgress signal frequency?

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I am trying to add progress observing to Qt's [FileDownloader](https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL) example.
It works, but not in the way as i desired - `downloadProgress` signal called too rare!
Just two time for ~300 Kb file.

This make it unusable to smoothly show download progress in GUI.

The code:

```
...
QNetworkReply* reply = m_WebCtrl.get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), SLOT(onDownloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

void FileDownloader::onDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal) 
{
    qDebug() << "Download progress:" << bytesReceived << bytesTotal;
}
```

The output:

`Download progress: 19954 from -1
Download progress: 288322 from -1
Download progress: 288322 from 288322`

Is there a way to make `downloadProgress` signal come much more frequently?

P.S. `libcurl` progress callback log:

`Download progress: 2753 of 0
Download progress: 4141 of 0
Download progress: 5995 of 0
Download progress: 7383 of 0
...`

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Easiest way is to recompile Qt and change the following line:

```
// in qtbase/src/network/access/qnetworkreply.cpp
const int QNetworkReplyPrivate::progressSignalInterval = 100;
```

...with a value (in milliseconds) that is lower than 100.

---

If you look at Qt source code for `QNetworkReply` (and related classes), you will find the following:

```
if (downloadProgressSignalChoke.elapsed() >= progressSignalInterval) {
    downloadProgressSignalChoke.restart();
    emit q->downloadProgress(bytesDownloaded,
                         totalSize.isNull() ? Q_INT64_C(-1) : totalSize.toLongLong());
}
```

So you can see that what controls the emission of the signal is the `downloadProgressSignalChoke` and the `progressSignalInterval`.

- `downloadProgressSignalChoke` is a [`QElapsedTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html) which is a member of the private Qt class `QNetworkReplyPrivate` and, as far as I know, you cannot change the duration returned (which are milliseconds).
- `progressSignalInterval` is a static constant member of `QNetworkReplyPrivate` which value is defined in `qnetworkreply.cpp` to `100`:

```
const int QNetworkReplyPrivate::progressSignalInterval = 100;
```

This means that the refresh interval is (apparently) set to a constant 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for such interesting idea, but i have neither time nor desire to recompile Qt :(
So i will just write `libcurl` Qt-wrapper